# OHCI haven’t interrupt when usb mouse wheel scrolling

Tags: usb, mousewheel

Ohci controller interrupt can be generated when the mouse button is left or right and the scroll wheel is pressed, but does not interrupt when the scroll wheel is rolled.

Doesn't the wheel roll interrupt? Or is there something that's not enabled on my controller? I'm not sure about this. Do you have a brother to teach me? thinks.

Comment: Mouse wheel scrolling and OHCI controllers are a very different levels in the communication and driver architecture. What exactly are you trying to do? Anyway, the USB host queries the USB device (mouse) once every few milliseconds to ask for a potential HID report. The mouse cannot directly trigger an event or interrupt.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.The reason is that i set the mouse to boot protocol. Problem was resolved after setting mouse to report protocol.